# Running docker containers in Jenkins and openshift

Tags: docker, jenkins, openshift

I'm working on building CI infrastructure for our project.
I am a bit experienced with `gitlab ci`, but currently we are using `jenkins` on top of `openshift`.

Using the scripted DSL, how can I load up containers during one of the stages?
The equivalent in `gitlab ci` is called `service`, which just require the image name.
How can I connect to that service as well?

In `jenkins` and even `openshift` docs it is not well covered, as opposed to the simple solution by gitlab.

Using Jenkins directly, it is possible to run images as "sidecar containers" (as their docs mention), something like:

`docker.with("postgres:9.6"){...}`

Since I'm running Jenkins inside openshift, it doesn't have permissions to use docker.

I want to use this feature for testing:

1. Run a few containers (DB, message queue etc...)
2. Run the tests against those containers
3. Report the result and tear down the containers

Comment: Can you add more content to the question please

Comment: @Kalanamith I have updated the question and added an example